# How to have 3 fetches in a javascript promise?

Tags: javascript, fetch, es6-promise

I'm having a bit of trouble figuring this out.

I have a fetch to wiki, but if that doesn't work, I want it to use a different link. Now if that doesn't work, I want it to send to a different link as the main default.

This is what I have right now which works great!

```
fetch(url)
.then(response => {
  if(response.ok){
    return response
  }

  else if (!response.ok) {
    return fetch(link + location)
  }
})
```

I'd appreciate any idea on how to add a third fetch. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just chain it onto the end with another `then`:

```
fetch(url)
    .then(response => {
        if (response.ok) return response;
        return fetch(link + location);
    })
    .then(response => {
        if (response.ok) return response;
        return fetch('whatever your third link is');
    });
```

Of course, Jonas's answer is much cleaner because it avoids repetition and generalizes this operation to any number of fallback urls.

Comment: Thank you! This is a lot easier for me to understand since this is already what I have. I'll give it a try! Thank you!

Comment: I'm having a moment of "Why didn't I try that in the three hours I've been working on this..." 
Thank you thank you!!!

Answer (score 5):

A helper might be elegant:

```
 async function fetchMirrors(...urls) {
   for(const url of urls) {
     const response = await fetch(url);
     if(response.ok) return response;
   }
   return null;
 }
```

So you can do:

```
  fetchMirrors(url, link + location, third).then(...)
```

Comment: I'll give this a try! Thank you for your quick reply1

Comment: Thank you for this. I will have to look this up to try and understand for..of loops better inside promises. Thanks again.

Comment: Thank you for sharing this resource @sripberger. I'll try and organize all these fetches with your method once I figure this out.